# Is there any way to send multipart form request to graphql in reactjs with apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, react-apollo

I am new to react with graphql.

I want to upload .pdf file to server via network interface.

All I need to do is write a graphql query using apollo client which sends multipart form data to server.

I tried to search it on google but I did't found any proper solution.

```
mutation createUser($user: myfile) {
    createData(myfile: $user) {
        id
        name
        email
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

GraphQL doesn't normally deal with multipart data or file uploads, but if you are writing your server yourself you can create a custom request type which has more fields than just the `query`, and thus make it work. [This guy did it here](https://medium.com/@danielbuechele/file-uploads-with-graphql-and-apollo-5502bbf3941e).

This is a rather roundabout way to go at it which will probably give you lots of headaches. I would recommend being less stubborn about the single endpoint, and use a different server to manage the upload. After all, there are lots of well tested libraries dealing with all "the devils details" surrounding uploads.